# Initializing Firebase auth object error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting an error whenever I try to run the app:

Here is .java class:

```
package com.safariagaming.flix;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class SignUpScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    //defining view objects
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonSignup;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    //defining firebaseauth object
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_screen);

        //initializing firebase auth object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        //initializing views
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        //attaching listener to button
        buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void registerUser(){

        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //checking if email and passwords are empty
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //if the email and password are not empty
        //displaying a progress dialog

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");

        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //calling register method on click
        registerUser();
    }
}
```

(I think that the error happens because I am not initializing firebase auth object correctly)

Here is my XML class

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:hint="Enter email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:hint="Enter password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="Signup" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my error message that I am encountering

```
03-29 18:14:49.700 9230-9230/com.safariagaming.flix E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.safariagaming.flix, PID: 9230
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.safariagaming.flix.SignUpScreen.registerUser(SignUpScreen.java:72)
                                                                      at com.safariagaming.flix.SignUpScreen.onClick(SignUpScreen.java:93)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Look in your log output for an explanation of why Firebase Auth is not initializing properly.  If it's no too big, post the log output for your app initialization.

Comment: Add an if-statement with `Log` statements immediately after `firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` to confirm that the code is executing and `firebaseAuth` is not null.

Comment: There could be a couple of things going on:

Check if `FirebaseApp` is getting initialized correctly. Make sure `FirebaseApp#getApp()` is non-null.
If not, then `FirebaseApp` is not correctly initialized, and hence `FirebaseAuth` is not getting initialized.

The only other case in which there is a `null` return on `FirebaseAuth#getAuth` is in multi-process made.
`FirebaseInitProvider` only works for the `default` process and not other processes when referrred to using
`android:process` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have defined the variables `email` and `password` **outside** the method `registerUser()`. It seems that your Button is not correctly set as well.

```
package com.safariagaming.flix;

/**
 * Imports...
 */

public class SignUpScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

   private String email = null;
   private String password = null;
   private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_screen);

  /**
   * Inits and code...
   */

    // Signup button on listener
    buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        // Verifications
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.empty_email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.wrong_email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.empty_password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Authenticating user
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.wrong_credentials, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            goDashboard();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
             }
         });
      }
   // onStart() state listener
   @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
             mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: @tassilo_tazz I edited my code. It seems that your listener is not correctly set and thus, not getting the user input. This is my code and works perfectly. Don't bother the different classes name.

Comment: This code is still causing me errors... Mind adding me on Skype?: tassilo.heinrich.tazz I'd really appreciate it. I've been trying to solve this for 4  hours now.

Comment: @tassilo_tazz Firebase docs advise you to add an `authStateListener(mAuth)` in `onStart()` and `onStop()`. Check my edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

This means your `mAuth` member variable is null.  You probably never assigned a value to it.  Assign it with `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` during onCreate() or at least some time before you call createUserWithEmailAndPassword on it.

Comment: If the code at the OP's pastebin link is the actual code being run, the initialization you describe is being done.

Comment: @BobSnyder FirebaseAuth.getInstance() will never return null, however.

Comment: @DougStevenson I already did that. look at the paste bin line 36.

Comment: @tassilo_tazz Can you absolutely prove that FirebaseAuth.getInstance() is returning null?  I've looked at the Firebase SDK code (I'm on staff here), and it doesn't look like that can ever happen.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that I already initialized it in onCreate() and I'm doing it just like they are telling me in the docs. Do you think by any chance we can talk over Skype because I really need to fix this problem? My skype is tassilo.heinrich.tazz

Comment: @DougStevenson If you want I can pay you but I just need this problem fixed and I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support if you want troubleshooting help.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @DougStevenson Can we assume that FirebaseAuth.getInstance will only return null if Firebase cannot connect to the network for some reason?

I am asking this because I am designing the failure scenario if this ever returns null? Should I ask the user to retry  after ensuring that their internet is on and connected, or are there other reasons because of which it can be null ?