# FirebaseAuth is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting a null return on my FirebaseAuth.getInstance in my code that's causing my app not to run. Here's my main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Firebase Auth
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    //Cloud vision
    private static final String CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY = "AIzaSyBHgLORJOy0BAp6PYL5DqX0hwQYAv8-3xE";
    public static final String FILE_NAME = "temp.jpg";
    private static final String ANDROID_CERT_HEADER = "X-Android-Cert";
    private static final String ANDROID_PACKAGE_HEADER = "X-Android-Package";
    //Cloud vision
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int GALLERY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 0;
    private static final int GALLERY_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 2;
    public static final int CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST = 3;
    //Cloud vision
    private TextView mImageDetails;
    private ImageView mMainImage;
    //Firebase instance variables
    //DATABASE
    /*
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mPhotosDatabaseReference;
    private DatabaseReference mVisionOutputDatabaseReference;
    private DatabaseReference mUserFeedbackDatabaseReference;
    */
    //AUTH
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    //Cloud vision
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Cloud vision
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Initialize Firebase
        //Database
        //mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        //Auth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

The last line is where I'm getting a null return.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you saying that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` is returning null?  A similar question was posted recently.  A Firebase developer looked at the source code and [said that is not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43106583/4815718).  Are you testing for null immediately after calling `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`?

Comment: What version of `firebase-auth` are you building with?

Comment: Auth 10.2.0 and Auth UI 1.2.0. and I was initially testing right before and then I tested after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. My database API package wasn't the right version for the Firebase UI version. I just never checked it because I was so focused on the Auth part.

Comment: Just curious--in case someone else reports this problem. What was the version of `firebase-database` that conflicted with `firebaes-auth` 10.2.0 and `firebase-ui` 1.2.0?

Comment: 10.2.1. Seems like Firebase UI stays one behind the actual Firebase. The latestest syncs can be found here: [link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

Comment: Thanks. When I try that combo of libs, I get a crash: `E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure` instead of null auth instance.  Maybe a difference in the device versions we are using.

Comment: I actually got the APK to install but it kept giving me a "Sorry your app closed" message.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have an internet connection you can get a null. If it's a slow connection it may not be available immediately.

Answer (score 0):

did you added

```
 mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    ////////////////
                } else {


                }
            }
        };
```

and in **onStart**

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart(); 

         mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    }
```

Comment: I added the onStart Method and I already had the listener below and I'm still getting a null statement.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `mFirebaseAuth` object you need to add in your `onStart` method a listener like this: `mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);`. Than you neeed to declare `private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;` and than in your `onCreate` method add this code:

```
    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    };
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added the onStart Method and I already had the listener below and I'm still getting a null statement

Comment: What is the value of `mFirebaseAuth` after you are calling `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`. Is it `null`?

Comment: Yes, it is null.

Comment: Did you enabled in your Firebase account, in `Authentication` -> `SIGN-IN METHOD` -> the `provider`? You need to enable the one your are using, `Email/Password`, `Google` and so on.

Comment: Yes, I do. I also have anonymous enable but have that nowhere in my providers. However I tried disabling that in Firbase and got no difference.

Comment: The saved instance is also null if that helps

Comment: Did you add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'` in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Yes that's in there.

Comment: In your `AndroidManifest`, have set this 2 permissions? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>' and '
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: I did not have  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />. I added it however it did not fix the issue

Comment: Delete your old `google-services.json` file, download it again from your account and put it you application folder.

Comment: Did that and no change. Good idea though. I have an SHA1 on my app does that change anything?

Comment: Yes, you need also to set your `SHA1`. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) you can take a look at how can be done. In the end, don't forget to put your `google-services.json` again in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I noticed that this tag was duplicated for some unknown reasons! When I removed the extra one, everything started to work correctly.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
```

Just thought to share this experience so maybe it may be helpful to others. I simply lost 4 hours to fix this :-/

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your Manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" /> </service>
```

If same service exists into you manifest, use only meta-data tag.